# jenkins svn plugin revert action slower than command line job?

Tags: windows, svn, jenkins, revert

I have three build machines with Jenkins v1.473 installed.

Let's call them machine A, B and C. All are running Windows 7 x64.
Machine B and C jenkins installation was carried over from machine A. I simply copied the folder over and everything was imported and works fine.

We initially had a Windows command line job that would call svn revert and then, svn update on a bunch of folders. After that, we would build our project. The average running time was about 10 mins. SVN version of the command line tools is 1.7 on all 3 machines (with tortoisesvn)

Since we were using command line svn commands, we didn't have access to $CHANGES when sending the job completion email, so we switched to the Jenkins svn plugin.
The switch was made on machine B and C first and after confirming it was working fine, we applied the same changes to machine A. The plugin version is 1.50.

Check-out Strategy is set to "*Use 'svn update' as much as possible, with 'svn revert' before update*".
Repository browser is set to Auto.

Under Jenkins->Configuration, Subversion Workspace Version is set to 1.7.
The other fields are left as-is (*Exclusion revprop name* is empty, *Validate repository URLs up to the first variable name* is unchecked, *Update default Subversion credentials cache after successful authentication* is checked)

Now, onto my issue.

The running time on machine B and C stayed about the same: about 10 mins.

However, on machine A, running time has more than doubled: it now averages 25 mins.
Looking at the job log, the revert part seems to be the culprit.

Is there a reason switching from svn command line to the plugin would make it run slower ? On top of that, *on one particular machine only* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging and testing several jobs across all machines, here's what I found out:

- command line tools are fairly faster than their plugin counterpart, most likely due to the speed of the programs themselves (compiled C binary vs SVNKIT which is written in Java and running on top of a JVM)
- machine A is also fairly slower than B and C, despite having similar specs, most likely because of other applications and services running at the same time (B and C are near-fresh installs, while A has been running for a longer time, with more applications installed etc)

In the end, I just split the clean/revert part from the update:

- Clean/Revert job is carried in command line (I/O heavy due to folder traversal I believe) so it is as fast as it can be
- Update (and update only, no revert done within the plugin) is then done with the plugin (fairly fast, less than a minute usually for several dozen files) which allows me to still have access to the CHANGES variable.

With this, I somehow managed to keep the building time on machine A nearly unchanged (around 10 mins).
Machines B and C however, have seen their building times greatly improved (from 10 mins to 5 mins in general)